# Is there a way to control join column name in OneToMany / ManyToOne bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We are in the process of implementing an application accessing a third party database model we don't have control over. We use Apache Camel JPA for database operations. These are two of our entities related in an OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship to each other. One `transaction` can have multiple `transaction_document` entries (OneToMany) and multiple `transaction_document` entries can only belong to one `transaction`(ManyToOne)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="transaction")
@Data
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "transaction_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "transaction_id_generator", sequenceName = "transaction_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long transactionId;
    .....
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "transaction", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<TransactionDocument> transactionDocuments = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction_document")
@Data
public class TransactionDocument {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "transaction_document_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "transaction_document_id_generator", sequenceName = "transaction_document_transaction_document_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long transactionDocumentId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Transaction transaction;
    ....
}
```

And the two related tables have this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transaction(
    transaction_id BIGSERIAL,
    ....
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transaction_document (
    transaction_document_id BIGSERIAL,
    transaction_id BIGINT,
    ....,
    CONSTRAINT transaction_document_fk FOREIGN KEY (transaction_id) REFERENCES transaction(transaction_id)
);
```

The issue is that when building up a test Camel route to verify the `transaction` entity is save correctly in the database `from("driect:start").to(jpa:my.path.to.Transaction")` I am getting an SQL exception complaining that column `transaction_transaction_id` does not exist. I believed what makes JPA (backed by hibernate) to look for this column name comes from `mappedBy = "transaction"` in our `OneToMany` annotation. Changing the name of the `transaction_document` column from `transaction_id` to `transaction_transaction_id` fixes the problem but we cannot do this because it will impact our third party software running against this data.

Any idea about how to deal with this

Comment: If I understood properly you have missed `@JoinColumn` annotation over `private Transaction transaction` field.

Comment: That was exactly the problem I had. I just hopped someone else will spot it too so I can accept the answer. Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.